# Reasoning Aptitude CSIR 15

Tags: volume, area

A single-celled spherical organism contains $70$% water by volume. If it loses $10$% of its water content, how much would its surface area change by approximately?

1. $3\text{%}$
2. $5\text{%}$
3. $6\text{%}$
4. $7\text{%}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r$ be the original radius the original volume of water is $$V_1=\frac{70}{100}\times \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\frac{14}{15}\pi r^3$$ & volume of organic material 
$$V_2=\frac{30}{100}\times \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\frac{2}{5}\pi r^3$$
 & surface area $S_0=4\pi r^2$

when it loses $10$% of water then remaining volume of water $$V_1'=\frac{90}{100}\times V_1= \frac{90}{100}\times\frac{70}{100} \times \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\frac{21}{25}\pi r^3$$ 
If $r'$ is the radius of remaining cell then new volume of cell $$V_1'+V_2=\frac{21}{25}\pi r^3+\frac{2}{5}\pi r^3$$
$$r'=\left(0.93 \right)^{1/3}r$$
hence the new surface area of cell $$S'=4\pi r'^2=4\pi \left(\left(0.93\right)^{1/3}r\right)^2=4\pi \left(0.93 \right)^{2/3}r^2$$

hence % change in surface area of the cell $$\frac{S'-S_0}{S_0}\times 100$$
$$=\frac{4\pi \left(0.93 \right)^{2/3}r^2-4\pi r^2}{4\pi r^2}\times 100=4.722877503\approx 5\ \text{%}$$

Comment: Why have you made it so complicated when jacks wasted life had answered it earlier in almost a line ?

Comment: I like this answer because it gives the exact % change; however, it's very likely they intended the problem to be solved approximately using calculus. But I'm giving the +1.

Comment: A much simpler way of going about it is to model the initial volume of the cell as $100$ units, of which $70$ are water and $30$ are "other". After the $10 \%$ decrease in water volume, you end up with $63$ units of water, which when added to the remaining $30$ units, gives $93$ units total. So the change in volume is $0.93$, and since volume is proportional to $r^3$, and surface area to $r^2$, you should quickly be able to see that the new rel. surface area is $0.93^{\frac 23}$, giving a percentage change of $100(1-0.93^{\frac 23}) \%$. Actually, I got to this mentally, it's a simple problem.

Comment: Actually i added the same solution one hour before he did, but got ashamed as it was way longer.

Answer (score 5):

If $V$ is its volume and $S$ is its surface area, $S$ is proportional to $V^{2\over3}$ so
$$
{dS\over S}={2\over3}{dV\over V}={2\over3}{0.1\times0.7V\over V}\approx0.05
$$

Comment: nice answer! i was actually calculating it the hard way!